# Corona SDK animation not working with the director class?

Tags: android, coronasdk

Hey there i am trying to use animations in my game but for some reason i get error
Here is my code i used for animation

```
local function animate( event )
    gear.rotation = gear.rotation + 10
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", animate);
```

This works if i use it without the director class
The director class is to change from scene to scene

I get the error message when i try to leave the class or when i go to other class
it but rotates until i try to leave the class

The error = attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'rotation' (a nil value)

Any help please
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
gear.rotation = 0

local function animate( event )
    gear.rotation = gear.rotation + 10
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", animate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely when you change scenes, your enterFrame is still running but the old scene is removing your gear object (but the gear variable still exists).  Make sure to remove that enterFrame listener before you change scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
local gear.rotation = 0

local function animate( event )
    gear.rotation = gear.rotation + 10
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", animate);
```

And when you leave the page, call:

```
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", animate);
director:changeScene("yourScene")
```

---

Still the problem exists, try the below code:

```
 local bg = display.newRect(0,0,display.contentWidth,display.contentHeight) -- or simply create a background

 -- create gear
 local gear.rotation = 0

local function animate( event )
    gear.rotation = gear.rotation + 10
end

bg:addEventListener("enterFrame", animate);
```

And when you leave the page, call:

```
bg:removeEventListener("enterFrame", animate);
director:changeScene("yourScene")
```

Keep coding..... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for my problem i just changed the local function 
to just function and it works.

```
 function animate( event )
     gate_a.rotation = gate_a.rotation + 2
 end
 Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", animate);
```

and when i leave the scene

```
 Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", animate);
```